# does not show any output or error in indexes of node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, indexing

This is my code for creating an index and finding the data using MongoDB, but it doesn't show any output or error.

I already install mongose, mongo-client, plus it does not contain any URL errors. Where did it go wrong?

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connection URL and database name
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
const dbName = 'myproject';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
function connectDB(){

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Failed to connect to the MongoDB server:', err);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");
  
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const collection = db.collection('mycollection');
  
    // Create an index on the 'name' field
    collection.createIndex({name: Dev,age : 20}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Failed to create index:', err);
        console.log(result);
        client.close();
        return;
      }
      // Find all documents where the 'name' field is equal to 'John'
      collection.find({name: 'dev'}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Failed to retrieve documents:', err);
          client.close();
          return;
        }
        console.log(docs);
        client.close();
      });
    });
  });
}

connectDB();
```

Comment: Are you getting the "Connected successfully to server" message?

Comment: no bro no output at all nothing print in the console when i run code it shows nothing no error or output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. The createIndex function takes an object as its parameter, where the keys are the names of the fields you want to index, and the values are either 1 (for ascending order) or -1 (for descending order). Your code seems to be passing the values 'Dev' and 20 instead of 1 or -1.
2. In the find function, you are looking for documents where the name field is equal to 'dev', but you created the index on the name and age fields, with age equal to 20. This means that the index will not be used to speed up the query, and the performance may be slow if you have a large number of documents in the collection.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connection URL and database name
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
const dbName = 'myproject';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
function connectDB(){

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Failed to connect to the MongoDB server:', err);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");
  
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const collection = db.collection('mycollection');
  
    // Create an index on the 'name' and 'age' fields
    collection.createIndex({ name: 1, age: -1 }, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Failed to create index:', err);
        client.close();
        return;
      }
      // Find all documents where the 'name' field is equal to 'dev'
      collection.find({ name: 'dev' }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Failed to retrieve documents:', err);
          client.close();
          return;
        }
        console.log(docs);
        client.close();
      });
    });
  });
}

connectDB();
```

This should create an index on the name and age fields, with name in ascending order and age in descending order. Then it will find all documents where the name field is equal to 'dev' and output them to the console.

Comment: bro,thanks for the notice but after given index as an ascending order and remove age, so its not contain any error but still didn't get the output

Comment: This is all good improvement, but if it's not even connecting to the DB it won't help.